# Plotting candlesticks with tight resolution - understanding "width" parameters

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been using tutorials for candlestick data and they work well for daily charts.  However, I'm guessing since they rely on default behaviour by the matplotlib.finance candlestick function, there are pieces I'm missing in my understanding for switching it to intraday.

My data looks like this (but I convert the date/time to numbers prior to the call to finance.candlestick)

```
                           high         low        open       close  volume        vwap
2013-09-18 18:05:00  126.343750  125.468750  125.468750  126.046875     721  126.285909
2013-09-18 18:10:00  126.296875  126.078125  126.078125  126.187500     271  126.194649
2013-09-18 18:15:00  126.234375  125.843750  126.234375  125.843750      83  126.157003
2013-09-18 18:20:00  125.984375  125.953125  125.953125  125.953125     505  125.953311
2013-09-18 18:25:00  126.250000  126.250000  126.250000  126.250000       1  126.250000
2013-09-18 18:30:00  126.250000  126.250000  126.250000  126.250000       0  126.250000
```

And the code (stripped of all the attempts I've made) I'm using is as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.85, 0.7])
# customization of the axis
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out', width=2, length=8,
               labelsize=12, pad=8)
ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(2)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)

ax.set_ylabel('Quote ($)', size=20)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(fiveminutelocator)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(oneminutelocator)

# candlestick call requires the following format:
#    (time, open, close, high, low, ...)
print(bars.to_records())
bars.index = bars.index.map(date2num)
candle_bars = bars[ ['open', 'close', 'high', 'low' ] ]
candle_bars = map(list, candle_bars.to_records())
finance.candlestick(ax, candle_bars, width=0.1, colorup='g', colordown='r')
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is as follows:

[image: Plot]

EDIT:
The problem lies with my lack of understanding of the relationship between "figure.size" which I gather is in inches, "figure.dpi", and the width parameters that get passed in for Line2D and Rectangles for patches in matplotlib.

I don't quite get how that relation works.  A smaller range of times in the (i.e. 10 millisecond bars, and a total range of 10 seconds) requires a tiny width in the finance.candlestick plot (0.000005 seems to work).  A larger range of times (day-bars and months of data) can use the default width of 0.8.

So what I do not understand is what the width is measured in.  It's described as "points".  However fiddling with DPI in the figure doesn't seem to do what I'd want it to do.

Comment: It looks like you're plotting dates but not specifying that you're using dates (Though maybe you are with your `oneminutelocator`, etc.).  (Try calling `ax.xaxis_date()`.)  However, the widths are in data units, not points. (Stroke widths are in points, not the width of the rectangle.) Matplotlib's internal date format is just a floating point number, where a difference of 1.0 corresponds to 1 day.  Therefore, a 10 millisecond bar width would be ~ 1e-7.

Comment: Thanks Joe.. I've been through a lot of iterations of that.
Data widths.. I think that clears it up enough for me to work something out.

Comment: When you say stroke widths, does that cover Line's and Line2D and such?  Or is it just fonts?

Comment: For strokes (i.e. the `linewidth` or `lw` kwarg), it's always in points, regardless of what type of artist it is.  If you look at the documentation, it gives units for things like strokes, etc.  Where the documentation doesn't specify a unit of measure, it's because it uses whatever `transform` it's given (data coordinates, unless you specify otherwise). Generally speaking, marker sizes, stroke/linewidth sizes, and font sizes are in points. (`scatter`'s marker sizes are a bit different.) Most other things will be in data coordinates, unless you're supplying a custom `transform`.